# karate: How to Run SSH command using karate

Tags: karate

I need to run command with ssh in mac ssh test01.dev.test.com' and currently could not send password .
Getting below mentioned error.

Output:
working dir :null
Pseudo -terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
permission denied please try again

- def command =
  """
  function(line) {
  var proc = karate.fork({ redirectErrorStream: false, useShell: true, line: line });
  proc.waitSync();
  karate.set('sysOut', proc.sysOut);
  karate.set('sysErr', proc.sysErr);
  karate.set('exitCode', proc.exitCode);
  }
  """
  Scenario:
- command('ssh test01.dev.test.com')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the basic CLI capabilities of Karate may be too limiting for SSH. We have a sample that shows how to use a Java library and use an SSH connection. It can be found here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/ssh/README.md

```
* def config = { user: 'ec2-user', host: '', privateKey: '' }
* def SshSession = Java.type('karate.SshSession')
* def ssh = new SshSession(config)
* ssh.input('pwd')
* ssh.input('whoami')
* ssh.input('exit')
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working. i am able  login with ssh and send command . But could not execute command . do i need to use  something other than ssh.input keyword?

Comment: @sangammamadapur I referred to this example: https://gist.github.com/wmcu/7dfc341f12c330618e47 - please take the help of someone who knows java and you should be able to figure out how to get it to work. do report back your findings to help others

Comment: i have added some wait functions it helped to run all inputs. Thanks @peter-thomas

Answer (score -1):

Karate is primarily used for testing web-services and not for managing shell or command line processes such as SSH. It is an open-source tool that combines API test-automation, mocks, performance-testing and even UI automation into a single, unified framework. It does have the ability to call command line processes via karate.fork() but it's not its primary use-case and may not have full support for handling such commands efficiently.

In your specific case, running SSH commands can be tricky due to security reasons and the need for password entry or the use of SSH keys.

If you really need to do this, you would probably want to consider other approaches or tools that are better suited for managing command line or terminal-based processes.

One of such ways could be using a language like Python with the paramiko library, which allows for SSH connections and command execution. Here's a basic example of what you could do:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('test01.dev.test.com', username='yourusername', password='yourpassword')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('your command here')

for line in stdout:
    print(line.strip('\n'))

ssh.close()
```

Another approach could be to use an expect script, or tools like Ansible for automation if this is part of a larger process.

Do keep in mind though that storing passwords in scripts is generally a bad practice from a security perspective. You might want to use SSH keys, or some form of secure secrets management for production use-cases.